# which apps should have this flag enable "REQUIRE_SECURE_ENV"

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-console, google-developers-console

Google has updated its policy today and require this new property in manifest file "**REQUIRE_SECURE_ENV**" mentioned in their document [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/limit-play-loading#:%7E:text=On%2Ddevice%20Android%20containers%20are,portions%20of%20the%20Android%20OS.). I don't understand which sort of application are using "on-device Android container" and how do I know whether my application(Category: Utility) is requiring this property in manifest or not?. Can anyone please elaborate about it. Thanks.

Comment: I guess an example are apps that you sell through Amazon Appstore. You can install and run apps from this store on Windows 11 in some kind of preview mode. With this flag your apps will run only in Android based systems.

Comment: @basileus so you are saying that I should add this property in my manifest file?

Comment: If you do not want your app to be run on such devices - yes, you should add it. If you do not mind running your app this way - then you do not have to.

Answer (score 2):

If your app loads third-party APKs into its own app space, and those apps reasonably execute as if they are installed in a normal Android environment due to your app intercepting and potentially proxying calls, your app is considered an on-device Android container app.

One popular example of an on-device Android container technology is "Anbox" (Android in a Box). Anbox allows you to run Android applications on a Linux-based system, such as Android apps on Ubuntu or other Linux distributions. It uses containerization technology, such as LXC (Linux Containers), to create a secure and isolated environment for running Android applications.

Apps can add this flag to their manifest to indicate they don't want to be run in an On-device Android Container

[Source](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/13678785)